# Is it possible to distribute HTML 5 IPhone application via AppleStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is it possible to distribute HTML 5 IPhone application via AppleStore?

Comment: if you start to develop an iPhone app in HTML5 what is the specification of HTML5 changes - will you then change your app? its not been given 100% buy in yet so think for a while about it before you spend a lot of time on it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to distribute an iPhone Web Application through the App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157576/is-it-possible-to-distribute-an-iphone-web-application-through-the-app-store)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a project called [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/). That allows Javascript application to use native API and distributed through App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, you can perhaps wrap your app in a container to distribute it on the app store. But not heard about something to do that yet.

BTW, an alternative app store exist for HTML5 apps:
http://www.openappmkt.com/